# Creating a name generator for Unity Project C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im currently doing a small project just for fun , in which i am making small randomly generated people civ.Im currently working on the function to handle the name generation and i cant quite figure out a good way , or effiecent way to complete this task. So far this is what i have :

```
    public void GenerateName() {
        string[] nameComponent1 = new string[] {"Ge","Me","Ta","Bo","Ke","Ra","Ne","Mi" };
        string[] nameComponent2 = new string[] {"oo","ue","as","to","ra","me","io","so" };
        string[] nameComponent3 = new string[] {"se.","matt.","lace.","fo.","cake.","end." };

        string nameCompfirst = nameComponent1[Random.Range(0, nameComponent1.Length)].ToString();
        string nameCompSecond = nameComponent2[Random.Range(0, nameComponent2.Length)].ToString();
        string nameCompThird = nameComponent3[Random.Range(0, nameComponent3.Length)].ToString();


    }

};
```

If you would be able to solve this for me , that would be awsome - or if you have a better suggestion please go for it. I am up for ideas

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to select one of strings randomly?

Comment: I want the strings to be chosen randomly and then all the nameComp variables to be added together to equal the name variable - thats at least how i was going to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use System.Random class but in your code it uses UnityEngine.Random instead, add this to the top of your class

```
using Random = System.Random;
```

Comment: How do you do that sorry , bit of a newbie

Comment: add that line to the top of your class like the following
`using Random = System.Random;

public class YOURCLASS: MonoBehaviour {
   /// code here
}`

Comment: i'm glad it helped!
please mark this answer so that other users will be able to see this solution

Comment: @IdoBenShalom, Others use what? Adding the name space system? all classes has it in c# and probable keanu.b removed it.

Answer (score 0):

If i truly understand you:

```
Random r = new Random();

string[] nameComponent1 = new string[] {"Ge","Me","Ta","Bo","Ke","Ra","Ne","Mi" };
    string[] nameComponent2 = new string[] {"oo","ue","as","to","ra","me","io","so" };
    string[] nameComponent3 = new string[] {"se.","matt.","lace.","fo.","cake.","end." };

string nameCompfirst = nameComponent1[r.Next(0, nameComponent1.Length)];
string nameCompSecond = nameComponent2[r.Next(0, nameComponent1.Length)];
string nameCompThird = nameComponent3[r.Next(0, nameComponent1.Length)];

string result = nameCompfirst + nameCompSecond + nameCompThird;
```

Comment: That doesnt seem to work , when i type Next it doesnt auto complete or - it has error 
"Random" does not contain a definition for "Next" and no extension method "Next"

Comment: Did you used `Random r = new Random();` and `r.Next()` ? It is wrong: `Random.Next()`

Comment: Yes , i put i wrote exactly : 

 Random r = new Random();
//This part doesnt auto complete
            string nameCompfirst = nameComponent1[r.]

Comment: What you mean auto complete? `string nameCompfirst = nameComponent1[r.Next(0, nameComponent1.Length)];` gives you one item of nameComponent1 randomly. Maybe you are about some thing else.

Comment: Is the **Random** shown by green color? In top of you class do you have this: `using System` ?

Comment: The awsner below solved my problem , now im able to do what you suggested